# How to handle uriParam before ngAfterViewInit?

Tags: typescript, angular-routing, angular7, angular-router-guards, angular-lifecycle-hooks

I try to pass information from one website to another. The two websites do not share the same url or server.

I have the idea that the best way is to use the URL parameters (http://some.url?param=value).
So if I'm not mistaken in the Angular life cycle, before the ngAfterViewInit callback.
By doing this, self.route.snapshot.queryParamMap.get('param') returns me null.

How can I get this param? Is there another (cleaner) way to pass information between 2 angular websites?

Initially my code was in the ngOnInit method. I moved this code to ngAfterContentInit but without any changes, the router remains empty.

I thought about parsing window.location.href, but it doesn't seem clean to me.

app.module.ts

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: 'profil', canActivate: [ Guard ], component: ProfilComponent },
  /* [...] */
  { path: '**', canActivate: [Guard], redirectTo: 'profil' },

];

/* [...] */

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    ProfilComponent,
    /* [...] */
  ],
  /* [...] */
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes),
  ],
  entryComponents: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

app.component.ts

```
@Component({
    selector: 'app-root',
    templateUrl: './app.component.html',
})
export class AppComponent implements AfterContentInit {

    constructor() {}

    ngAfterContentInit() {
        const self = this;
        self.logger.debug(self.route); // empty
        self.logger.debug(self.route.snapshot.queryParamMap.get('param')); // null
        if (self.route.snapshot.queryParamMap.get('param')) {
            localStorage.clear();
            localStorage.setItem('externalParam', self.route.snapshot.queryParamMap.get('param'));
        }
    }
}
```

app.component.ts

```
@Component({
    selector: 'app-root',
    templateUrl: './app.component.html',
})
export class AppComponent implements AfterContentInit {

    constructor() {}

    isAuth(): boolean {
        return !!localStorage.getItem('externalParam');
    }

    ngAfterContentInit() {
        const self = this;
        self.logger.debug(self.route); // empty
        self.logger.debug(self.route.snapshot.queryParamMap.get('param')); // null
        if (self.route.snapshot.queryParamMap.get('param')) {
            localStorage.clear();
            localStorage.setItem('externalParam', self.route.snapshot.queryParamMap.get('param'));
        }
    }
}
```

app.component.html

```html
<div id="container" class="h-100">
    <app-nav *ngIf="isAuth()"></app-nav>
    <div id="body" class="h-100">
        <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    </div>
</div>
```

nav.component.ts

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-nav',
  templateUrl: './nav.component.html',
})
export class NavComponent implements OnInit {

    param: any;

    constructor() {}

    ngOnInit() {
        this.param = localStorage.getItem('externalParam');
    }
}
```

The following files are simplified for the example

nav.component.ts

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-nav',
  templateUrl: './nav.component.html',
})
export class NavComponent implements OnInit {

    param: any;

    constructor() {}

    ngOnInit() {
        this.param = localStorage.getItem('externalParam');
    }
}
```

nav.component.html

```html
<h1>{{param}}</h1>
```

As mentioned above, for the moment I can't get my parameter from the URL. The Router object is empty.

Comment: Why can't you directly make HTTP requests from one server to another? Angular applications run in the front end and can't communicate with one another.

Comment: In fact, the parameter I pass from one application to another is a single-usage code that provides information about the current user. We can see it as a SSO. I want to keep this information from one site to another without the user having to reconnect to each navigation.